# Resources to learn APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, apex-managed-sharing

I am starting on with Salesforce, and having trouble finding good resources for learning APEX especially with some practice exercises. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What resources have you tried? Are you interested in any particular focus? Do you have Premier Support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this APEX workbook to be a very valuable resource to trying to learn Apex.  If you re an experienced coder, some if it may be a little elementary, but it really does a good job of teaching you the basics of the language and using it to interact with tha platform

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.pdf

Comment: Ninja, In the first example he uses static method, I don't understand what exactly the static does.Could you please help me understand it.

Comment: Is it similar to main method in java?

Comment: This is a very different question.  In order to get the community to see it and others to benefit from it, I would ask any specific Apex related questions as a separate question.